# Question closed for "promote or discredit a specific idea, theory, cause, group or person"?

Tags: discussion

[It](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/72201/is-there-evidence-that-there-ever-wasnt-contact-across-the-bering-strait) was a question about evidence, that's it. How is that not a valid question? It's a question about prehistory, which is allowed.

If the promotion was that it looked for evidence, well yeah. If the discredit was that it was trying to discredit a theory that didn't look at evidence, well yeah. Isn't that the whole point of sites like this?

Comment: Counter question: Exactly what theory do you think you're looking to discredit here?

Comment: I'm looking for evidence. My question here is why was it closed exactly.

Comment: Maybe it was due to an idea, idk.

Comment: I was just speculating on why it was closed, I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

First off, I wasn't one of the close voters (I rather like questions on this subject in fact), so for exact reasoning, one of them would have to pipe up. But I can provide some observations.

The question, as currently phrased, does seem to have an agenda of proving something else is wrong. The actual question in the text is *very* leading, rather than neutrally phrased. Our users here don't like to be led around.

More generally, it seems like its looking for one little damning snippet of information, rather than enlightenment on the subject. It might be a good idea to try to level that out a bit?

---

I will add though that I have a personal historical hobby horse on this subject. You can see [I've written about it before](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/is-there-any-evidence-of-post-landbridge-travel-across-the-bering-strait/16790#16790), so yes I fully understand that land bridges are not required for modern humans.

Due to that part of my heritage, I hang out in a lot of online places where Native Americans exchange ideas. There's one revisionist strain I bump into a lot, where people like to construct a "Bering Land Bridge Theory" as a strawman to pound the stuffing out of. There seems to be no end to the new finds that people can tout as destroying this imaginary theory. I'm sure that's cathartic, but its also bogus. You can search [the Wikipedia page on this subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peopling_of_the_Americas) in vain for that phrase. Everyone who seriously studies this issue knows that boats *are used* in Beringia, and *were used* historically.

There is a theory that one particular migration may have used a temporary ice-free corridor between the Alaskan glaciers rather than boats. These theories are called "coastal migration" vs. "interior migration". But there's no good way to prove either of them aside from circumstantial evidence of timing. We just have really good evidence that at least one of the two happened.

The point of all this is that this particular subject quite often has people looking to beat up on a strawman they heard about, rather than honestly asking for info.

Comment: I edited it, just asked for evidence